# Power Query Transform to Date Only shows no data values in Excel

Tags: excel, transform, powerquery

this week I try to use Power Query in Excel to connect to an OData feed. This seems to work when I connect I get results. However I have to do some transformations, otherwise, the data is useless.

Now I have this problem. Once connected to the OData feed I get this result:
[image: Result odatafeed]

The column "Begindatum" is of the type: Date/Time/Timezone

What I need is just date. So I use Transform and set the column to Date Only

[image: Result after transformation to Date Only]

This is the result as expected. However, when I choose Close & Load in the Query Editor window, the date column is empty.

[image: Endresult in Excel]

What am I doing wrong? I haven't got a clue.

I use Excel 2013 on a windows 8.1 machine. Cultureinfo set to en-US

[Update]
After some more trial and error, I found that this issue occurs when I remove columns. In the original source, before the "Begindatum" there are several other columns. As soon as I remove one of these columns, and I refresh the data, the value of the column "Begindadtum" is set to null. That is even before I choose Load & Close. I can change the type of the column "Begindatum" into Date. This is no problem. But removing columns before or after this column, I have a problem. So changing the original structure to only the columns needed causes dates not to show anymore. (null value)

[Update requested M-code]

```
let
Source = OData.Feed("https://aaa.zzzzzz.com/odata/Published_OData_service_Contracten"),
Contracten_table = Source{[Name="Contracten",Signature="table"]}[Data],
#"Changed Type with Locale" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Contracten_table, {{"ID", type text}}, "en-US"),
#"Extracted Date" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Changed Type with Locale",{{"Begindatum", DateTime.Date, type date}}),
#"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Extracted Date",{"ID", "createdDate", "changedDate", "Begindatum", "ConcatContractCode", "ContractID", "ContractSelecteerConcat", "DienstverbandPercentage", "Einddatum", "Einddatum_proeftijd", "EinddatumTijdelijkContract", "Instellingsnummer", "Registratienummer", "Contract_Medewerker"})
```

in 
   #"Removed Other Columns"

I wonder if this is a bug in Power Query.

[Update 2018-04-24]
the ODatafeed is served by Mendix. As this particular feed is the only one having this problem, I have asked our supplier to test it as well. They have the same problem, only with this feed. Therefore they opened a support ticket at Mendix. Most likely the problem is caused in their software. That is why I will close this issue.

Comment: That is strange... have you tried converting the column to a decimal or text type after converting it to a date? Just to see if it will properly convert those those and load?

Comment: Yes, I tried that. Still no luck. It is strange behavior. This week I will work on it again.

Comment: Can you also share the relevant M code please?